# NO System settings in Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: 12.04

When I installed elementary OS theme, it came with its own System settings to Ubuntu 12.04.5. When I uninstalled it, the default System settings window does not appear anymore. I mean, it shows the window, but I have no access to any configuration. This message is displayed, not extacly literal, because I'm translating it from portuguese to english:

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJRWK.png)
"No configuration has been found. Install some and reinitialize switchboard".

I've been tried reinstall gnome-control-center, ubuntu-desktop and all remains the same? Could someone please help?

Thank you all.

Comment: You could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-control-center`, and also, try to launch it from a terminal window. Any interesting outputs?

Comment: Yup, broken gnome i guess.

Comment: You might consider installing a newer version of Ubuntu instead as support for 12.04 expires in less than a month. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases